# How to access a property of a model in _layout.cshtml

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Well I am generating email templates using cshtml.

And I have one of the template like this.

```
@model Api.Model.SignUpViewModel

@{
    Layout = "layout";
}
```

And in `SignUpViewModel` I have got a property `isUnsubscribable`

So in layout page I have to show a link for Unsubscribe based on this.

And I have few other Email Models which have this property, some others does't have this.

How can I send this data to `Layout.cshtml`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to create a parent ViewModel with your isUnsubscribable property. Then make your SignUpViewModel inherit from that parent.

Then in your layout page, your Model is as follows:

```
@model Api.Model.ViewModel
//Access your property here
```

And in your cshtml page, you will have the child viewmodel:

```
@model Api.Model.SignUpViewModel
```

This will work because both pages are getting what they need, when you pass the model in from the controller.

Comment: if one of the model does't inherit the parent ViewModel. Can I check that for null? And not through an error?

Comment: If you don't inherit from the parent, when you pass the model from the controller the layout view will throw an exception because it's not the right type. But as far as I see, this should work for the question that you have asked. You just check from the child, what the value of the parents isUnsubscribable field is.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to send data to layout. It is already accessible there using below given syntax

```
@Model.isUnsubscribable
```

Comment: Well Some of the other Model, Such as WelcomeViewModel does't have the same property

Comment: Either you have to try inheritance between models as @Zingers suggested or you should add that property in other models as well